# How do I preserve a complex object across Activity restarts?

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity, lifecycle

Say I have a Java Bean object which is serializable. I want to store it away safely when an Activity goes through onDestroy() *on purpose* (i.e. onSaveInstanceState() is *not* called).

I am looking for a way which doesn't involve creating a database and write the object to that (mostly since a) Android's DB API is horrible and b) since databases make application updates a nightmare, because there is no decent support for applying migrations).

I thought about serializing the object to a ByteArrayOutputStream, base64 encode that and write it to a SharedPreferences file as a string. Or is that too far off?

**UPDATE**

Maybe that serialize-to-string idea wasn't that bad after all, seems to work out pretty well. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
    public static String objectToString(Serializable object) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        new ObjectOutputStream(out).writeObject(object);
        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();

        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream b64 = new Base64OutputStream(out);
        b64.write(data);
        b64.close();
        out.close();

        return new String(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static Object stringToObject(String encodedObject) {
    try {
        return new ObjectInputStream(new Base64InputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedObject.getBytes()))).readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

in onDestroy() I can then simply write the Base64 string to a preference file, where it's safe until I read it again during the next activity launch. It's a lot faster than I expected and unless your beans carry huge amounts of data, it works pretty well. And even better, you don't have to maintain a DB schema.

Still, I'm curious about how others do this.

Comment: Is it not possible to just use the Bundle instead?

Comment: how? you can only access the bundle if your activity goes through onSaveInstanceState(), i.e. when it's being destroyed by the runtime.

Comment: Awesome! I used your approach and it works.  Only issue I had was the Base64InputStream in Android SDK does not have a constructor that has one parameter it now has an additional int flag parameter.  Just set that to 0 or 8 if you have any url info in the Object.

Comment: Bah, Base64InputStream is only available since Android 2.2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html

Comment: Yes true. However, you can simply use one of the many free Base64 implementations out there. Or link against Apache commons-codec and use ProGuard to remove the unused classes.

Answer (score 9):

> I am looking for a way which doesn't
>   involve creating a database and write
>   the object to that (mostly since a)
>   Android's DB API is horrible and b)
>   since databases make application
>   updates a nightmare, because there is
>   no decent support for applying
>   migrations).

Android's API is actually fairly reasonable, mostly because it's a thin wrapper over the SQLite API, and the SQLite API is fairly reasonable for an embedded database. Moreover, Android does provide assistance for schema upgrades on app upgrades, via `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

> It's a lot faster than I expected and
>   unless your beans carry huge amounts
>   of data, it works pretty well.

I have heard of many more developers running away screaming from serialization than I have heard of people having long term success with it. Just within the past few days, here on SO #android, I had an exchange with somebody trying desperately to rip serialization out of his app by the roots.

> And even better, you don't have to maintain a DB schema.

Oh yes you do. What do you think is going to happen when you update your application and your class is modified? Doing the [bookkeeping](http://macchiato.com/columns/Durable4.html) to figure out how to deserialize old versions of the class from a new version of a class is a chore and is one of the reasons developers abandon serialization. Also, do not forget that serialization is not transactional, whereas SQLite is.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree at all. Having to maintain a database to store a simple object temporarily seems more than just a little excessive to me. Plus, I am aware of SQLiteOpenHelper and all its limitations, and I found DB migrations to be a major pain in the back.

Plus, there is NO maintenance required here, since I can simply clear() the editor before storing an object, regardless of its structure. Think document based database, there is no schema. With a DB, I would have to DROP TABLE whenever the model changes.

Comment: Matthias method works great if you are saving a complex object and don't want to go through the hassle of defining all the columns for each datapoint on an Object.

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a nice approach of un/marshalling any beans or activity states. We all know how much Activity's onStoreInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() is a pain.

My acitivities simply store their states in onPause() and restore them in onCreate() lifecycle hooks via direct object serialization.

Serialization via a String like you do, is of course possible but less suitable for big data and causes a lot of overhead. Moreover Preferences are actually there to store preferences, not data :) Unfortunately, the Parcelable / Parcel what we could use for this purpose, does not recommend to store to persistent storage.

So what's left over is a simple object serialization - fortunately android SDK has implementation of the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream classes with all drawbacks and benefits - like we would also do in a non-android Java world, a simple:

```
ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(yourPojo)
```

would do the magic for us, (remember to implement the Serializable marker-interface)

Also, you may want to look in following APIs of a Context - ContextWrapper - Activity, which are very useful to cache local data (such as images) etc:

```
.getCacheDir()
.getDir()
.openFileInput()
.openFileOutput()
```

happy hacking :)