# Save a listview menu

Tags: android, persistence

I am building a menu using a ListView and ArrayAdapters. When I run the app, I can add items to the ListView due to a EditText and Button that adds whatever is typed into the EditText to the ListView.

My issue comes in when I close the app. when I close the app, the ListView resets. I need the ListView to save the items that were added from the EditText. My app uses ArrayAdapters, ArrayLists, ListView, Button, EditText, and onClickListeners.

I just need good tutorials on how to save data that is added to a ListView while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to save data to persistent storage. Start with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) from Google.

In your case you may save to a simple file or to SQLite database if your data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

these two tutorial can help you to save everything that you want:

[Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

and for save property of a view or component you should study about `Serialization` and `Deserialization`. For this you can follow these questions:

[Serializing Android Views - causes InvalidClassException from IllegalAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779436/serializing-android-views-causes-invalidclassexception-from-illegalaccessexcep)

[How do I serialize an object and save it to a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android)

and for your main question this question can help you, too:

[How do I preserve a complex object across Activity restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636623/how-do-i-preserve-a-complex-object-across-activity-restarts)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[The official android Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) has a full-fledged example of displaying SQLite data in a list view and also saving it. You should check it out.